# Win32 API C struct in ComboBox items

Tags: c, winapi, combobox

Does anybody know how to add items from a `struct` to a ComboBox in C like in HTML - using the Win32 API in C and neither C# nor C++?

```
struct item {
  char *label, 
  int value;
};
```

So when we retrieve the selected item we retrieve the value and not the displayed string.

Comment: You can use `CB_SETITEMDATA` to associate a pointer-sized data value with an item, and `CB_GETITEMDATA` to retrieve it.

Comment: Do you mean after adding all strings, with cb addstring say blue red white I make a loop to cb_setitemdata  specifying indexed 0,1,2 with 12,13,14  as values if 12 means blue?

Comment: @c-dev - you need call `CB_SETITEMDATA` just after `CB_ADDSTRING` or `CB_INSERTSTRING` and use returned index from this message for   `CB_SETITEMDATA` , but not assume 0,1,2

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`CB_SETITEMDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775909(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CB_GETITEMDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775859(v=vs.85).aspx) messages.

Basically, after you insert a new string in the combo-box, e.g. via [`CB_ADDSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775828(v=vs.85).aspx), the zero-based index of the added string is returned on success.

Then you can use this index with [`CB_SETITEMDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775909(v=vs.85).aspx), associating to that item (having that index) your own custom data (passed via *pointer* in the `lParam`).

Similarly, you can retrieve that data using [`CB_GETITEMDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775859(v=vs.85).aspx), specifying in the `wParam` the 0-based index of the item you want to retrieve the data from.

**P.S.** You may want to use some higher-level more convenient [helper macros for ComboBoxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485900(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of raw Windows messages, like `ComboBox_SetItemData` or `ComboBox_GetItemData`.