# WinAPI C++ GUI: Is it possible to attribute an ID to each item of a ComboBox

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, combobox

I'm relatively new to Windows API development and I'm writing a graphical C++ program using it.
I looked in the Microsoft documentation and I can't find if there is a way to assign a unique identifier to each element of a ComboBox.

##### The issue

I currently fill the ComboBox with translated strings.
I could get each translated text and use something like strcmp, but that means I have to clone my code for each possible element instead of using a simple comparison...

##### Remarks

1. I create the ComboBox using `CreateWindow`.
2. I define each ComboBox element using `SendMessage` with `CB_ADDSTRING`.
3. I retrieve the selected element using `GetWindowText` using the ComboBox handler.

So the question is: **Is it possible to assign and retrieve an ID to each element of a ComboBox.**
Another small question: Do you recommend me to use the windowsx.h macros instead of using the "pure" WinAPI functions?

Comment: Use `CB_SETITEMDATA` and `CB_GETITEMDATA` messages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40884732/4603670

Comment: There's different options.... If you sort the strings you want to add ahead of time, then you already know where they're going to live in the combo box. If you don't want to do that, you could use CB_SETITEMDATA and pass an index or a pointer to a structure and of course use CB_GETITEMDATA on the backend.